# Select and Change

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="if" value="mag" onclick="mag">MAG</input>
    <input type="radio" name="if" value="ceg" onclick="ceg">CEG</input>
</form>

<form class="mag1" action="includes/signup.ini.php" methode="POST">
    <input type="text" name="first">1</input>
</form>

<form class="ceg1" action="includes/signup.ini.php" methode="POST">
    <input type="text" name="first">2</input>
</form>

<script>
    function mag() {
        document.getElementByClassName("mag1").style.display="block";
    }
</script>
```

In the css file i set the display to none. But the script isn't work for me and it isn't do anything

Comment: A few issues.... `onclick="mag"` missing `()` and `getElementByClassName()` is incorrect. It is missing an **s** on the end of element(s) `getElementsByClassName()` which also returns a node list so you would need to iterate through the list or select a specific index.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Missing `s` in your selector method name. Although which returns a collection of elements, so you need to get the first element from the collection using the index.

```
function mag() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("mag1")[0].style.display="block";
  //                -^-                 -^^^-
}
```

---

Or use [`Document#querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method instead.

```
function mag() {
  document.querySelector(".mag1").style.display="block";
}
```

---

Although you need to invoke the function inside [`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/onclick) attribute value.

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="if" value="mag" onclick="mag()">MAG
  <input type="radio" name="if" value="ceg" onclick="ceg()">CEG
</form>
```

**FYI :** `input` tag is a selfclosing tag, so `</input>` is invalid(just remove that).

---

**UPDATE 1:** In case you want to toggle the visibility then the above code is not enough.

```css
.ceg1,
.mag1 {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script>
  function mag(ele) {
    document.querySelector(".mag1").style.display = ele.checked ? "block" : "none";
    document.querySelector(".ceg1").style.display = ele.checked ? "none" : "block";
  }

  function ceg(ele) {
    document.querySelector(".ceg1").style.display = ele.checked ? "block" : "none";
    document.querySelector(".mag1").style.display = ele.checked ? "none" : "block";
  }
</script>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="if" value="mag" onchange="mag(this)">MAG
  <input type="radio" name="if" value="ceg" onchange="ceg(this)">CEG
</form>

<form class="mag1" action="includes/signup.ini.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="first">1
</form>

<form class="ceg1" action="includes/signup.ini.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="first">2
</form>
```

---

**UPDATE 2:** or use a common function and update display property based on the checked value, this would be the better way to do it.

```css
.ceg1,
.mag1 {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script>
  function toggle(ele) {
    document.querySelector(".mag1").style.display = ele.value == 'mag' ? "block" : "none";
    document.querySelector(".ceg1").style.display = ele.value == 'ceg' ? "block" : "none";
  }
</script>
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="if" value="mag" onchange="toggle(this)">MAG
  <input type="radio" name="if" value="ceg" onchange="toggle(this)">CEG
</form>

<form class="mag1" action="includes/signup.ini.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="first">1
</form>

<form class="ceg1" action="includes/signup.ini.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="first">2
</form>
```